Can't create custom personalized login page in spring security 6.2.4
I am trying to understand spring security, I have this problem where I want to create a custom made login html but I cannot seem to handle it.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}

@Controller
class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Please Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Please Log In</h1>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.</div>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

I tried following official spring site, I did everything from there but when I host it on localhost and try to access /login it shows me spring defailt login page instead of my custom made one

Your filterChain method is missing an @Bean method, effectivly rendering the configuration useless.

Unfortunately the Spring docs are sometimes a bit out of context, assuming that everybody knows the additional steps to take, which isn't always convenient especially for newbies. To get your sample running, you need to apply @Bean to the SecurityFilterChain for Spring Boot to pick it up:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}

